# R: Calculating year to date sum

Tags: r

I would like to calculate sum of sales from the beggining of the year to the newest date.

My data:

```
ID  Date     Sales
1   11-2016  100
1   12-2016  100
1   01-2017  200
1   02-2017  300
```

MY YTD should be 200+300

Comment: I know it's 500, I'd like to use it for bigger data :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` to summarise by year. `lubridate` is also useful to `group_by` year:

```
df1<-read.table(text="ID  Date     Sales
1   11-2016  100
1   12-2016  100
1   01-2017  200
1   02-2017  300",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1$Date <- as.yearmon(df1$Date,format="%m-%Y")

library(dplyr);library(lubridate)
df1%>%
group_by(Year=year(Date))%>%
summarise(Sales=sum(Sales))

   Year Sales
  <dbl> <int>
1  2016   200
2  2017   500
```

Answer (score 0):

In a business setting, year-to-date sales (YTD) are usually calculated for each month.  None of the current answers does that, so here is a solution using the latest version of **tidyverse** and `base::cumsum()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# changed input data to help understanding the results
import_sales <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Date,     ~Sales,
  "1", "10-2016", 120,
  "2", "11-2016", 240,
  "3", "12-2016", 450,
  "4", "01-2017", 360,
  "5", "02-2017", 230,
  "6", "03-2017", 310,
)

sales_data <- import_sales %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Date = lubridate::my(Date),
    Year = lubridate::year(Date),
    Month = lubridate::month(Date),
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(
    Year,
    Month
  ) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    Sales_Month = base::sum(Sales, na.rm = TRUE),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(
    Year,
    Month
  )

sales_data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(
    Year
  ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Sales_YTD = base::cumsum(dplyr::coalesce(Sales_Month, 0)),
    Sales_Year = base::sum(Sales_Month, na.rm = TRUE),
  ) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(
    Year,
    Month,
    Sales_Month,
    Sales_YTD,
    Sales_Year,
  )
```

Here is the result:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
   Year Month Sales_Month Sales_YTD Sales_Year
  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1  2016    10         120       120        810
2  2016    11         240       360        810
3  2016    12         450       810        810
4  2017     1         360       360        900
5  2017     2         230       590        900
6  2017     3         310       900        900
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you `Date` field is `character` and last four digits represent `year`.

Then you can filter where it equals current year with below:

```
df<-read.table(text="ID  Date     Sales
1   11-2016  100
1   12-2016  100
1   01-2017  200
1   02-2017  300",header=T)

sum(df[substr(df$Date,4,7)==format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"),]$Sales)
[1] 500
```

Comment: But I can't use Sys.Date as 02-2017 is not current date

Comment: `year(Sys.Date())` will return `2017`

Comment: You will need to load the `lubridate` package to use `year()`

Comment: @AndrewGustar You are right. I missed that, so I have changed the code with `format`

Comment: @MarlenaKuc I have revised code for getting current year as `format(Sys.Date(),"%Y")`

Answer (score -1):

This will sum all values for the current calendar year `sum(df$Sales[format(df$Date, "%Y") == format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")])` - you might need to make sure your `df$Date` variable is of class Date